# Prevent Snackbar from dismissing on action click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-snackbar, snackbar

How to prevent Android Snackbar from dismissing on setAction onclick, Thanks

```
Snackbar.make(rootlayout, "Hello SnackBar!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
   .setAction("Undo", new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           // Snackbar should not dismiss
       }
   })
   .show();
```

Comment: snackBar.show(); inside onClick

Comment: @GaneshPokale, that's not works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a somewhat cleaner solution for achieving this, which doesn't require reflection. It's based on knowning the view ID of the button within the Snackbar. **This is working with version 27.1.1 of the support library, but may no longer work in a future version if the view ID will be changed!**

First, set your snackbar action using an empty OnClickListener:

```
snackbar.setAction("Save", new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {}
});
```

Afterwards, add a callback to the snackbar (before showing it). Override the onShown function, find the button using `R.id.snackbar_action` and add your own OnClickListener to it. The snackbar will only be dismissed when manually calling `snackbar.dismiss()`, or by swiping if the snackbar is attached to a CoordinatorLayout (how to disable the swipe is a different SO question).

```
snackbar.addCallback(new BaseTransientBottomBar.BaseCallback<Snackbar>() {
    @Override
    public void onShown(Snackbar transientBottomBar) {
        super.onShown(transientBottomBar);

        transientBottomBar.getView().findViewById(R.id.snackbar_action).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // your code here
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, by design `Snackbar` shouldn't stay there after the action click, that's why it is non-configurable parameter.

Diving into code I could find enough seams in order to do that by reflection.

```
public static void doNotHideSnackbar(Snackbar snackbar) throws NoSuchFieldException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException {
    final Field sHandler = BaseTransientBottomBar.class.getDeclaredField("sHandler");
    sHandler.setAccessible(true);
    final Method handleMessage = Handler.class.getMethod("handleMessage", Message.class);
    final Handler originalHandler = (Handler) sHandler.get(snackbar);
    Handler decoratedHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what) {
                case 0:
                    try {
                        handleMessage.invoke(originalHandler, Message.obtain(originalHandler, 0));
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    sHandler.set(snackbar, decoratedHandler);
}
```

This is tested and works with support library version `25.3.1`.

### Usage

```
final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(root, "Hello SnackBar!", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Undo", new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

snackbar.show();

try {
    doNotHideSnackbar(snackbar);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

### Result

[image]

**BEWARE**, this is not the solution you should prefer to stick with, as long as API may change from version to version. You'd better consider implementing your custom `Snackbar`alike view. But as a fast workaround you can consider using this reflectioned version.

Comment: I've played a bit with this, and I found something strange... dismissing the `Snackbar` is _partially_ prevented: neither calling `dismiss()`, nor setting the duration (not indefinite) works, only swiping on screen (but callbacks are not called in this case either)! I also tried to implement handling and forwarding the other case to the original handler in the switch statement (0: show, 1: dismiss), with no result close to the original one.

Comment: thanks a lot but how to hide it next when required ?

Answer (score -1):

Better late than never - here's how i did it.

```
private fun showSnackbar() {
        if(snackbar == null) {
            //init snackbar
            snackbar = Snackbar.make(mainCoordinator, R.string.snackbar_no_network, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                    .setAction(R.string.snackbar_no_network_action) {
                        checkConnection()
                    } // action text on the right side
                    .setActionTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.snack_green))
            //set background color
            snackbar!!.view.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.main_dark_gray))
        }
        //show
        snackbar!!.show()
    }

private val handler = Handler()
private fun checkConnection() {
    handler.postDelayed(checkConnectionRunnable, 500)
}

private val checkConnectionRunnable = Runnable {
    if (!NetworkUtil.isOnline(context)){
        showSnackbar()
    }
}
```

Comment: This will hide and show snackbar in 500ms, which is not what OP asks.